# Anchor links stopped working in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink, anchor

I made this website : http://lesgitesduchienvert.be 2 years ago with loads of anchor links to navigate in the pages. The problem is that suddenly the links stopped working in chrome!!
It works perfectly in Safari, Mozilla, IE, ... and on mobile it works with chrome too!

At first I thought it might be because of the smoothScroll but it actually seems they don't work at all... I have looked all over but can't seem to find someone with that exact issue. Tried a few test but no apparent changes.

Has anyone seen that issue somewhere? Any idea to fix it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I just browsed to your website from chrome and all anchors seem to be working without problems.

Comment: It might be because of your chrome version? Mine is up to date, what about yours? It doesn't work on my computer nor on my client's computer. Btw one is a macbook the other a pc.

Comment: Mine is up to date

Comment: That's just weird I have tried on about 5 computers and it never works... Any idea what might be the difference between yours and ours? It could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Updating the scroll script made the trick :) It was a few years old...

Comment: Had the same issue but with jquery.localscroll.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this, it works across all browsers and replicates the smoothscroll effect perfectly.

Open Smoothscroll.js and replace with the following code

```
/*!
 * smooth-scroll v9.1.1: Animate scrolling to anchor links
 * (c) 2016 Chris Ferdinandi
 * MIT License
 * http://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll
 */

(function (root, factory) {
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
    define([], factory(root));
} else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
    module.exports = factory(root);
} else {
    root.smoothScroll = factory(root);
}
})(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : this.window || this.global, function (root) {

'use strict';

//
// Variables
//

var smoothScroll = {}; // Object for public APIs
var supports = 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in root;     // Feature test
var settings, eventTimeout, fixedHeader, headerHeight, animationInterval;

// Default settings
var defaults = {
    selector: '[data-scroll]',
    selectorHeader: '[data-scroll-header]',
    speed: 500,
    easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
    offset: 0,
    updateURL: true,
    callback: function () {}
};


//
// Methods
//

/**
 * Merge two or more objects. Returns a new object.
 * @private
 * @param {Boolean}  deep     If true, do a deep (or recursive) merge [optional]
 * @param {Object}   objects  The objects to merge together
 * @returns {Object}          Merged values of defaults and options
 */
var extend = function () {

    // Variables
    var extended = {};
    var deep = false;
    var i = 0;
    var length = arguments.length;

    // Check if a deep merge
    if ( Object.prototype.toString.call( arguments[0] ) === '[object Boolean]' ) {
        deep = arguments[0];
        i++;
    }

    // Merge the object into the extended object
    var merge = function (obj) {
        for ( var prop in obj ) {
            if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) ) {
                // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
                if ( deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]' ) {
                    extended[prop] = extend( true, extended[prop], obj[prop] );
                } else {
                    extended[prop] = obj[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
        var obj = arguments[i];
        merge(obj);
    }

    return extended;

};

/**
 * Get the height of an element.
 * @private
 * @param  {Node} elem The element to get the height of
 * @return {Number}    The element's height in pixels
 */
var getHeight = function ( elem ) {
    return Math.max( elem.scrollHeight, elem.offsetHeight, elem.clientHeight );
};

/**
 * Get the closest matching element up the DOM tree.
 * @private
 * @param  {Element} elem     Starting element
 * @param  {String}  selector Selector to match against (class, ID, data attribute, or tag)
 * @return {Boolean|Element}  Returns null if not match found
 */
var getClosest = function ( elem, selector ) {

    // Variables
    var firstChar = selector.charAt(0);
    var supports = 'classList' in document.documentElement;
    var attribute, value;

    // If selector is a data attribute, split attribute from value
    if ( firstChar === '[' ) {
        selector = selector.substr(1, selector.length - 2);
        attribute = selector.split( '=' );

        if ( attribute.length > 1 ) {
            value = true;
            attribute[1] = attribute[1].replace( /"/g, '' ).replace( /'/g, '' );
        }
    }

    // Get closest match
    for ( ; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode ) {

        // If selector is a class
        if ( firstChar === '.' ) {
            if ( supports ) {
                if ( elem.classList.contains( selector.substr(1) ) ) {
                    return elem;
                }
            } else {
                if ( new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + selector.substr(1) + '(\\s|$)').test( elem.className ) ) {
                    return elem;
                }
            }
        }

        // If selector is an ID
        if ( firstChar === '#' ) {
            if ( elem.id === selector.substr(1) ) {
                return elem;
            }
        }

        // If selector is a data attribute
        if ( firstChar === '[' ) {
            if ( elem.hasAttribute( attribute[0] ) ) {
                if ( value ) {
                    if ( elem.getAttribute( attribute[0] ) === attribute[1] ) {
                        return elem;
                    }
                } else {
                    return elem;
                }
            }
        }

        // If selector is a tag
        if ( elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === selector ) {
            return elem;
        }

    }

    return null;

};

/**
 * Escape special characters for use with querySelector
 * @public
 * @param {String} id The anchor ID to escape
 * @author Mathias Bynens
 * @link https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape
 */
smoothScroll.escapeCharacters = function ( id ) {

    // Remove leading hash
    if ( id.charAt(0) === '#' ) {
        id = id.substr(1);
    }

    var string = String(id);
    var length = string.length;
    var index = -1;
    var codeUnit;
    var result = '';
    var firstCodeUnit = string.charCodeAt(0);
    while (++index < length) {
        codeUnit = string.charCodeAt(index);
        // Note: there’s no need to special-case astral symbols, surrogate
        // pairs, or lone surrogates.

        // If the character is NULL (U+0000), then throw an
        // `InvalidCharacterError` exception and terminate these steps.
        if (codeUnit === 0x0000) {
            throw new InvalidCharacterError(
                'Invalid character: the input contains U+0000.'
            );
        }

        if (
            // If the character is in the range [\1-\1F] (U+0001 to U+001F) or is
            // U+007F, […]
            (codeUnit >= 0x0001 && codeUnit <= 0x001F) || codeUnit == 0x007F ||
            // If the character is the first character and is in the range [0-9]
            // (U+0030 to U+0039), […]
            (index === 0 && codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039) ||
            // If the character is the second character and is in the range [0-9]
            // (U+0030 to U+0039) and the first character is a `-` (U+002D), […]
            (
                index === 1 &&
                codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039 &&
                firstCodeUnit === 0x002D
            )
        ) {
            // http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#escape-a-character-as-code-point
            result += '\\' + codeUnit.toString(16) + ' ';
            continue;
        }

        // If the character is not handled by one of the above rules and is
        // greater than or equal to U+0080, is `-` (U+002D) or `_` (U+005F), or
        // is in one of the ranges [0-9] (U+0030 to U+0039), [A-Z] (U+0041 to
        // U+005A), or [a-z] (U+0061 to U+007A), […]
        if (
            codeUnit >= 0x0080 ||
            codeUnit === 0x002D ||
            codeUnit === 0x005F ||
            codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039 ||
            codeUnit >= 0x0041 && codeUnit <= 0x005A ||
            codeUnit >= 0x0061 && codeUnit <= 0x007A
        ) {
            // the character itself
            result += string.charAt(index);
            continue;
        }

        // Otherwise, the escaped character.
        // http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#escape-a-character
        result += '\\' + string.charAt(index);

    }

    return '#' + result;

};

/**
 * Calculate the easing pattern
 * @private
 * @link https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
 * @param {String} type Easing pattern
 * @param {Number} time Time animation should take to complete
 * @returns {Number}
 */
var easingPattern = function ( type, time ) {
    var pattern;
    if ( type === 'easeInQuad' ) pattern = time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
    if ( type === 'easeOutQuad' ) pattern = time * (2 - time); // decelerating to zero velocity
    if ( type === 'easeInOutQuad' ) pattern = time < 0.5 ? 2 * time * time : -1 + (4 - 2 * time) * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    if ( type === 'easeInCubic' ) pattern = time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
    if ( type === 'easeOutCubic' ) pattern = (--time) * time * time + 1; // decelerating to zero velocity
    if ( type === 'easeInOutCubic' ) pattern = time < 0.5 ? 4 * time * time * time : (time - 1) * (2 * time - 2) * (2 * time - 2) + 1; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    if ( type === 'easeInQuart' ) pattern = time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
    if ( type === 'easeOutQuart' ) pattern = 1 - (--time) * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity
    if ( type === 'easeInOutQuart' ) pattern = time < 0.5 ? 8 * time * time * time * time : 1 - 8 * (--time) * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    if ( type === 'easeInQuint' ) pattern = time * time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
    if ( type === 'easeOutQuint' ) pattern = 1 + (--time) * time * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity
    if ( type === 'easeInOutQuint' ) pattern = time < 0.5 ? 16 * time * time * time * time * time : 1 + 16 * (--time) * time * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    return pattern || time; // no easing, no acceleration
};

/**
 * Calculate how far to scroll
 * @private
 * @param {Element} anchor The anchor element to scroll to
 * @param {Number} headerHeight Height of a fixed header, if any
 * @param {Number} offset Number of pixels by which to offset scroll
 * @returns {Number}
 */
var getEndLocation = function ( anchor, headerHeight, offset ) {
    var location = 0;
    if (anchor.offsetParent) {
        do {
            location += anchor.offsetTop;
            anchor = anchor.offsetParent;
        } while (anchor);
    }
    location = location - headerHeight - offset;
    return location >= 0 ? location : 0;
};

/**
 * Determine the document's height
 * @private
 * @returns {Number}
 */
var getDocumentHeight = function () {
    return Math.max(
        root.document.body.scrollHeight, root.document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        root.document.body.offsetHeight, root.document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        root.document.body.clientHeight, root.document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
};

/**
 * Convert data-options attribute into an object of key/value pairs
 * @private
 * @param {String} options Link-specific options as a data attribute string
 * @returns {Object}
 */
var getDataOptions = function ( options ) {
    return !options || !(typeof JSON === 'object' && typeof JSON.parse === 'function') ? {} : JSON.parse( options );
};

/**
 * Update the URL
 * @private
 * @param {Element} anchor The element to scroll to
 * @param {Boolean} url Whether or not to update the URL history
 */
var updateUrl = function ( anchor, url ) {
    if ( root.history.pushState && (url || url === 'true') && root.location.protocol !== 'file:' ) {
        root.history.pushState( null, null, [root.location.protocol, '//', root.location.host, root.location.pathname, root.location.search, anchor].join('') );
    }
};

var getHeaderHeight = function ( header ) {
    return header === null ? 0 : ( getHeight( header ) + header.offsetTop );
};

/**
 * Start/stop the scrolling animation
 * @public
 * @param {Element} anchor The element to scroll to
 * @param {Element} toggle The element that toggled the scroll event
 * @param {Object} options
 */
smoothScroll.animateScroll = function ( anchor, toggle, options ) {

    // Options and overrides
    var overrides = getDataOptions( toggle ? toggle.getAttribute('data-options') : null );
    var animateSettings = extend( settings || defaults, options || {}, overrides ); // Merge user options with defaults

    // Selectors and variables
    var isNum = Object.prototype.toString.call( anchor ) === '[object Number]' ? true : false;
    var anchorElem = isNum ? null : ( anchor === '#' ? root.document.documentElement : root.document.querySelector(anchor) );
    if ( !isNum && !anchorElem ) return;
    var startLocation = root.pageYOffset; // Current location on the page
    if ( !fixedHeader ) { fixedHeader = root.document.querySelector( animateSettings.selectorHeader ); }  // Get the fixed header if not already set
    if ( !headerHeight ) { headerHeight = getHeaderHeight( fixedHeader ); } // Get the height of a fixed header if one exists and not already set
    var endLocation = isNum ? anchor : getEndLocation( anchorElem, headerHeight, parseInt(animateSettings.offset, 10) ); // Location to scroll to
    var distance = endLocation - startLocation; // distance to travel
    var documentHeight = getDocumentHeight();
    var timeLapsed = 0;
    var percentage, position;

    // Update URL
    if ( !isNum ) {
        updateUrl(anchor, animateSettings.updateURL);
    }

    /**
     * Stop the scroll animation when it reaches its target (or the bottom/top of page)
     * @private
     * @param {Number} position Current position on the page
     * @param {Number} endLocation Scroll to location
     * @param {Number} animationInterval How much to scroll on this loop
     */
    var stopAnimateScroll = function (position, endLocation, animationInterval) {
        var currentLocation = root.pageYOffset;
        if ( position == endLocation || currentLocation == endLocation || ( (root.innerHeight + currentLocation) >= documentHeight ) ) {
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
            if ( !isNum ) {
                anchorElem.focus();
            }
            animateSettings.callback( anchor, toggle ); // Run callbacks after animation complete
        }
    };

    /**
     * Loop scrolling animation
     * @private
     */
    var loopAnimateScroll = function () {
        timeLapsed += 16;
        percentage = ( timeLapsed / parseInt(animateSettings.speed, 10) );
        percentage = ( percentage > 1 ) ? 1 : percentage;
        position = startLocation + ( distance * easingPattern(animateSettings.easing, percentage) );
        root.scrollTo( 0, Math.floor(position) );
        stopAnimateScroll(position, endLocation, animationInterval);
    };

    /**
     * Set interval timer
     * @private
     */
    var startAnimateScroll = function () {
        clearInterval(animationInterval);
        animationInterval = setInterval(loopAnimateScroll, 16);
    };

    /**
     * Reset position to fix weird iOS bug
     * @link https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/issues/45
     */
    if ( root.pageYOffset === 0 ) {
        root.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
    }

    // Start scrolling animation
    startAnimateScroll();

};

/**
 * If smooth scroll element clicked, animate scroll
 * @private
 */
var eventHandler = function (event) {

    // Don't run if right-click or command/control + click
    if ( event.button !== 0 || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey ) return;

    // If a smooth scroll link, animate it
    var toggle = getClosest( event.target, settings.selector );
    if ( toggle && toggle.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' ) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default click event
        var hash = smoothScroll.escapeCharacters( toggle.hash ); // Escape hash characters
        smoothScroll.animateScroll( hash, toggle, settings); // Animate scroll
    }

};

/**
 * On window scroll and resize, only run events at a rate of 15fps for better performance
 * @private
 * @param  {Function} eventTimeout Timeout function
 * @param  {Object} settings
 */
var eventThrottler = function (event) {
    if ( !eventTimeout ) {
        eventTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            eventTimeout = null; // Reset timeout
            headerHeight = getHeaderHeight( fixedHeader ); // Get the height of a fixed header if one exists
        }, 66);
    }
};

/**
 * Destroy the current initialization.
 * @public
 */
smoothScroll.destroy = function () {

    // If plugin isn't already initialized, stop
    if ( !settings ) return;

    // Remove event listeners
    root.document.removeEventListener( 'click', eventHandler, false );
    root.removeEventListener( 'resize', eventThrottler, false );

    // Reset varaibles
    settings = null;
    eventTimeout = null;
    fixedHeader = null;
    headerHeight = null;
    animationInterval = null;
};

/**
 * Initialize Smooth Scroll
 * @public
 * @param {Object} options User settings
 */
smoothScroll.init = function ( options ) {

    // feature test
    if ( !supports ) return;

    // Destroy any existing initializations
    smoothScroll.destroy();

    // Selectors and variables
    settings = extend( defaults, options || {} ); // Merge user options with defaults
    fixedHeader = root.document.querySelector( settings.selectorHeader ); // Get the fixed header
    headerHeight = getHeaderHeight( fixedHeader );

    // When a toggle is clicked, run the click handler
    root.document.addEventListener('click', eventHandler, false );
    if ( fixedHeader ) { root.addEventListener( 'resize', eventThrottler, false ); }


};


//
// Public APIs
//

return smoothScroll;

});
```

Make sure the link to smoothscroll.js is called below the jquery.js, and then, beneath those, paste the following:

```
<script>
smoothScroll.init();
</script>
```

Replace any links that use the class

```
<a class="smoothscroll" href ="">
```

is replaced with date-scroll instead. Anything that uses the smoothscroll class won't work in chrome.

Try it out! It worked for all my sites affected by this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue with sites I have built running Chrome's latest version (62.0.3202.84). I took a look at your site and see that you are using SmoothScroll, that's your issue there. They are supposed to be releasing a patched version of SmoothScroll that will fix this, and I hope they do soon! I use it on just about all the sites I build! See more here and watch for updates
https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll/issues/27

And here for the latest version of SmoothScroll 
https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll

Comment: I found a perfect solution for this, which completely replicates the smoothscroll effect and requires very little effort to replace. Follow these instructions:

Answer (score -2):

Just change the class on your link to  `class="external"`